# Cannot resolve symbol in MainActivity and some issue with Build Gradle

Tags: android, android-activity

**This Is MainActivity Code**  *Star Word Are Cannot Resolve*

```
package com.earningdude;

import android.support.**v7**.app.**AppCompatActivity**;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    **@Override**
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(**R**.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**And This Is My Build Gradle Module: app Code**

```
package com.earningdude;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: there is no `build.gradle`, nor any logs.

Comment: have you try to sync gradle?

Comment: Yes Many Times But Its Show Error

Comment: check the you Build Gradle with `appcompat` and its version also `design` and its version like example if you are using `targetSdkVersion 27` then use `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0' implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'`

Comment: @MusicCompany unless you won't tell us which errors these are, this is not a question, but only permits wild guessing. please add more details, in case you intend to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

On <kbd>R</kbd> press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to *Import Class*

Comment: Sir I Have A problem In This Now   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

Comment: can you post screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

on your left side there would be projects hierarchy > click to build.gradle (app level) > hover around appccompact and check if update is available >  sync .